# How to use current_admin_user in Active admin dashboard section

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I want to show section in dashboard only if user is superadmin.

Pseudocode (talk is cheap, show me the code).

```
  if current_admin_user.superadmin?
    section "Super admin menu" do
      div do
        link_to "Admins permissions", admin_admin_permissions_url
      end
    end
  end
```

How can I do that?

Is there a simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't actually tried this, but according to the release notes, as of [0.4.1](http://reverbhq.com/blog/2012/02/active-admin-0-4-1-released/) you can conditionally show *most* components by passing an optional "if" condition:

```
section "Super admin menu", if: -> { current_admin_user.super_admin? } do
  div do
    link_to "Admins permissions", admin_admin_permissions_url
  end
end
```